# .NET Cryptography KeyedHashAlgorithm fakes

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, microsoft-fakes

I cannot seem to find any shims for `KeyedHashAlgorithm` (for example for `HMACMD5`) under `System.Security.Cryptography.Fakes`. I can find shims for mostly all other cryptographic functions. Are `KeyedHashAlgorithm` fakes simply not available?